# How to get text filed value in ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a table with dynamic data from database, each row consist of a text filed and 2 link (accept or reject). then if user clicks on any of these link, the row will disappear and the rest of the rows are only visible in table.

I get ID of each row with ajax by clicking on each link, however I also need to get the text-field value. 
how can I get it? 
I need to have in ajax cause after getting value I need to insert in database with php+sql.

this is my **ajax part for link**:

```
 $('a.accept').click(function(d) {
    d.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'Test.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&accept=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
          parent.remove();
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

how can I include text filed value in it?

please comment me which I'm really in need to solve it,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add manually your text to the GET request.

(snippet)

```
data: 'ajax=1&accept=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-','') + '&text=VALUE',
```

Substitute `text` with the name you want to be received in PHP. Substitute `VALUE` with the text entered on the page that you want to grab - and don't forget to encode the value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the name of id of the textfield first. Then you could do something like this:

```
var textboxvalue = $('name or id of textfield').val();
```

Then you will need to append this value to your data string:

```
data: 'ajax=1&textvalue='+textboxvalue+'accept=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
```

Then you can use `$_GET['textvalue'];` to get the value of textbox.

Comment: this is my text field:
Applicant Number<input type="text" size="2"  placeholder="e.g. 5"  id="textvalue<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>" name="textvalue<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>">
and on php part: 
if(isset($_GET['accept'])) {
echo $_GET['accept'];
echo $_GET['textvalue'];
}
BUT it only shows the accept value to me

Comment: Could you provide your html code for the entire row? i.e. the textbox and the two links

Comment: <div class="record" id="record-'<?php echo $ApplicantID;?>'">
          <tbody>
             <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" >
                 th><a href="applicant_profile.php?ApplicantID=<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>" class="name"><?php echo $Company_name; ?></a> <br /></th>
            <td class="tc"> 
                                Normal<input name="agreemnet<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>" type="radio" value="normal" id="hidetarget<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>" checked="checked" />

Comment: Conditional<input name="agreemnet<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>" type="radio" value="conditional" id="showtrigger<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>"  />
                                      <div id="showhidetarget<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>">
     Applicant Number<input type="text" size="2"  placeholder="e.g. 5"  id="textvalue<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>" name="textvalue<?php echo $ApplicantID ?>">

              </div>

</td>

Comment: <td class="tc">
             <ul class="actions">
                                                    <?php if($Level==1){ ?>
              <li><a href="?accept=<?php echo $ApplicantID; ?>" class="accept" onclick="jaascript"><img src="graphics/accept.png" alt="edit" /></a></li>              <li><a href="?delete=<?php echo $ApplicantID; ?>" class="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"><img src="graphics/cross.png" alt="delete" /></a></li>
                                                        <?php }?></ul></td> <?php }} else echo "No records.";?></tr>

Comment: these three comments are all together my table in html part

Comment: @user1328273 - put them in your question, they will be **much** easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use following and you're good to go. Also you had extra '});' at the end line of JS fragment. I had it removed. But make sure you give id to text fields in following pattern :

```
text-fld-RECORD_ID
```

where

```
RECORD_ID
```

is the ID of the record.

```
$('a.accept').click(function(d) {
    d.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var id = parent.attr('id').replace('record-','');
    //make sure that text field has ID in pattern 'text-fld-RECORD_ID'
    var text_fld = $('#text-fld-'+id).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post', // I suggest using post; get will be harmful in such occasions
      url: 'Test.php',
      data: {ajax:1,accept:id,text:text_fld},
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
          parent.remove();
        });
      }
    });  
});
```